# Android Google Map latitude and longitude compression

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am doing one application for Track routes of bike.

I am fetching all the latitude and longitude per second.

Now I want to store that latitude and longitudes in my local database or on server. But the problem is data becomes very large. So I want to store that data with optimization, means I want same result but I want to reduce data size.

Please help me, if anybody knows any algorithm or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this device-side, there is an open-source maps utility library created by the Android Maps team that includes a method to encode a set of `LatLng` objects into an [encoded Polyline string](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm).

Android Maps Utils library project:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Sample app that shows how to use the library:
https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android

Use this library in your project, then call the `PolyUtil.encode()` method to encode a set of `LatLng` objects into a String, which you can store in your database:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L68

Then, call `PolyUtils.decode()` method to decode a set of LatLng objects from the same String:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L29

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its looks like good, but the problem is with the latitude and longitude I need to store speed, distance, max speed, average speed etc. So how can I manage that things?

Comment: I don't know of any encoding system specific to spatial data that includes speed and other values, so you'd need to come up with one yourself, or modify the above to encode speed and other attributes as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and more practical solution is to reduce the frequency of location updates:

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,refresh_freq, 0, locListener);
```

Try to update your position each 3 seconds (refresh_freq = 3000) instead of each one second (refresh_freq = 1000), this will reduce your data to the third. (Considering that the bike speed is not to high, this will not affect your precision)

EDIT: According to your comment in the previous answer, I can understand that you need only to get the speed, and distance. So why don't you only calculate them instantly and overwrite them in each update:

```
distance = (distance + old_location.distanceTo(new_location));

average_speed = (distance/(total_time/1000))*3.6;

instant_speed =  (((old_location.distanceTo(new_location))/refresh_freq)/1000)

if (instant_speed>max_speed){
max_speed = instant_speed;
}
```

Insert all of these lines **in your onLocationChanged** (Location loc) method. Now you won't need to store your positions in a database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this already but I have very large amount of data so this will not work for me, but your answer is right.