# Using polygon class in google maps without having maps view

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an Android application where I need to check whether a GPS point lie inside a region (or polygon). I am therefore planning to use Polygon class provided by Google Maps. But, this require a map view to construct a polygon. I don't want to use a map view. Kindly tell if there is a class or some API by which polygon can be used. I have come to know of a PolyUtil class but it requires importing another library.

Thanks,
Arpit

Comment: You can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17820108/4195406 But if you want to know a region, you probably still need a map view to display your region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this lib [android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/):

```
PolyUtil.containsLocation(LatLng point, java.util.List<LatLng> polygon, boolean geodesic)
```